# Can you safely cast a C structure with non-const members to an equivalent structure with const members?

Tags: c, constants

Is it safe to cast from one structure to another(both have the same shape) when one has non-const members and the other has const members? The code demonstrates what I'm trying to do..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nonConst {
    int value;
    struct nonConst * next;
};

struct Const {
    const int value;
    struct nonConst * const next;
};

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {

    struct nonConst * nc = (struct nonConst*)malloc(sizeof(struct nonConst));
    nc->next = NULL;
    nc->value = 8888;

    struct Const * c = (struct Const*)nc;/*cast the non-const members to const members*/

    fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", c->value);


    return 0;
}
```

Is the above safe(or safe in certain situations) or can I expect problems?

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc()`!

Comment: No, but similar code would be safe if instead of a `struct nonConst`, you first used the memory as a `union U { struct nonConst nc; struct Const c; }`, by the "common initial sequence" rule.

Comment: @aschepler-> I never considered a union for this situation. I'll have to explore the possibilities.

Comment: @aschepler -> reading KR's The C programming Language(2nd edition) it states(about unions page 147): "so long as the usage is consistent: the type retrieved must be the type most recently stored". So this would raise the same aliasing issue if I tried to use a union to capture both structures right? I couldn't store a non-const member structure and then retrieve a const member structure.

Comment: @G4143 Yes, but there's an exception to that rule when a union contains two structs with members at the start of both structs in the same order that have "compatible types". (And adding `const` creates a compatible type.)

Comment: @aschepler Thanks you for that tip. It sounds like a union will be the perfect fit for this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This falls in an area not clearly covered by the standard. Firstly, memory with no type is allocated by `malloc`.

Writing to dynamically allocated space sets the *effective type* of the memory. But the standard doesn't say whether `nc->value` "imprints" an entire `struct nonConst` , or if it just writes an `int`.  Similarly, it doesn't say whether `fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", c->value);` requires that an entire effective `struct Const` be present, or whether it just reads a `const int`.

This distinction is important because it is OK to write an `int` and read a `const int` from the same memory location (the strict aliasing rule mentions this specifically).

---

Some major compilers take the position that `nc->value` and `c->value` imprint/require the entire struct, not just the member involved. So, in practical terms, I think it would not be safe to use this code.

I go into more detail about the topic in the second part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51851962/1505939).